# Using cascade with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

My question is that can I use cascade with composite Primary key?
I have a table FbUser and a table `FbFriends`. `FbFriends` table has `UID` and `FID` as composite primary key, In other tables it is represented as `foreign key(UID,FID)`
If I make statement `delete from FbFriends where UID="10" and FID="2"` CASCADE, Will that delete the child rows as well?

Comment: Yes,definitely this is the purpose we use cascade

Comment: @ZainShah120 not sure if that gonna work or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ON DELETE CASCADE` is an attribute of the foreign key.  It is not a clause that you add to your `DELETE` statement.  If the foreign key is defined to delete child rows when the parent is deleted, it doesn't matter whether the foreign key is defined on a single column or on multiple columns, the delete will cascade.

Personally, though, I'm not a big fan of cascading deletes or any other "magic" that happens outside of the logic in a piece of code.  I've seen way too many cases where an ORM is misconfigured to do a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` rather than an `UPDATE` or where a developer builds a script that deletes and reloads some number of rows in a table inadvertently create a mess when a cascading foreign key or a trigger that wasn't looked at caused modifications to some number of other tables.  If the original developer fails to realize that those tables are potentially impacted by his change, he'll certainly fail to test the data in those tables and the change can rather easily get promoted to production before users start seeing the problem and crying.  Sure, it's more verbose to explicitly delete from the child table before the parent table.  But doing so generally makes it much more likely that someone can read and follow your code in its entirety.

In the Oracle realm, for example, Tom Kyte is [against cascade deletes](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4402306800346205969).  You can also find various cases where [cascading constraints caused unexpected behavior](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/16/sql-server-curious-case-of-disappearing-rows-on-update-cascade-and-on-delete-cascade-part-1-of-2/) because the developers maintaining a system didn't remember that someone long ago had configured the constraints in a particular way.  Personally, I'd much rather get an error telling me that the database can't delete a row because there are child rows rather than potentially losing data that I didn't intend to lose.

Comment: thank you for giving a great discussion, can you refer any tutorial or blog where someone is "AGAINST" the cascade or cascade gave pain to someone?

Comment: @user1765876 - Added a couple of blog discussions.

Comment: I have to agree, I have also seen a problem occur where millions of records were being deleted and locked up the system. Further in many cases I want it to fail  if there are records ina particualr child tables. (Think deleting a customer who has orders, deleting the order could adjust your financials) Most dbas I know are not fans of cascade deletes or updates.

Comment: @JustinCave very important query, If I have (A,B,C) as PK in parent table and (B,C) are foreign keys in child table with delete cascade enabled, If I delete a record containing (B,C) from parent table will that delete all the records from child table?

Comment: @HLGEM please have alook

Comment: @user1765876 - That question doesn't make sense.  A foreign key can only be defined in a child table if it points to a single row in the parent (generally enforced by a primary key but occasionally by a unique constraint).  If (A,B,C) is the primary key, (B,C) would have to be a separate unique constraint in order to even create the foreign key constraint on the child table

Comment: @JustinCave (B,C) are declared as foreign key in child table

Comment: @user1765876 - Then there must be a unique constraint on `(B,C)` in the parent table.  There must be exactly one parent for any given child row.  At least, that is how every database I've encountered works and how the SQL standard is defined. You tagged your question with a number of different databases, perhaps you are actually using a database that has a very non-standard feature.  If that's the case, you'd want to create a second question that was specific to that database about how that database handled the non-standard setup.

Comment: @JustinCave yes the parent rows are unique but I haven't put the Unique constraint yey, I am using Mysql

Comment: @user1765876 - If MySQL allows what you're stating it allows, you'll need to create a new MySQL-specific question about how it would handle the situation you describe.

Comment: @user1765876: if you are using MySQL why did you tag the question with Oracle and SQL Server as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its more like a DB issue